# how to take take variable from main and use it in a function?

Tags: c, function, variables, cs50

So my goal for the moments it write some code that will count the amount of sentences, words, and letters in a set of string that is inputed by the user. My problem however is that when i try to use the user input for my functions that i will later call, it does not allow me to use the variable "text" which is the users input, within my functions.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int count_letters(string x);
int main(void)

{
    string text= get_string("Text: ");
    printf("%s", text);
}
 int letters=0, words= 1, sentence=0; // Problem lays here I cannot use variable "text" in my functions how do iI make it so I can do that ??
 int count_letters(string x) // counter for letters
{
for ( int i =0, t =strlen(text); i<t; i++)
{
    if (isalpha(t[i]))
    {
        letters++;
    }
}return letters;
}
int count_words (string x) //counter for words
{
for ( int s =0, y = strlen(text); s<y;  s++ )
     {
          if(isspace(text[s]))
         {
           words++;
       }
    }return words;
 }
    int count_sentences(string x) // counter for sentences
 {
  for ( int s =0, y = strlen(text); s<y;  s++ )
  {
      if (ispunct(text[s]))
       {
          sentence++;
       }
    }return sentence;
  }
```

Comment: If you call `count_letters( text );` from the function `main`, then the function `count_letters` will have access to the content of `text` through the function argument `x`. The same applies also for the function `count_words`. So all you have to do is type `x` instead of `text` in those functions.

Comment: Your code would be easier to understand (both for yourself and for other people) if you used consistent indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```c
    printf("%s", text);
}
 int letters=0, words= 1, sentence=0; // Problem lays here I cannot use variable "text" in my functions how do iI make it so I can do that ??
```

Here you have a random closing curly bracket. As @Andreas Wenzel pointed out, there is no consistent indentation style. I would use an IDE of sorts, or at least only use tabs for indentation. It would make errors like this easier to spot. I don't even know how this code would compile.